# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR app Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, avd

Olá, estou tendo uns problemas com um app.. Eu estou tentando rodar no AVD, mas dá no consolo

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR..
```

Eu fui na Android Manifest e troquei o `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` por `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`..

Funcionou, porém não executa se eu colocar no celular e executar.. Funciona apenas com o run direto no Eclipse..

Comment: Vitor, você realmente precisa do `installLocation` sendo `preferExternal` ou `internalOnly`? Não poderia usar `installLocation="auto"`?

Answer (score 1):

Esse post nesse site pode ajudar a você: [Link Android](http://androidandsandu.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/how-to-resolve-installfailedcontainerer.html)

Você pode usa  android:installLocation="auto"

Comment: Olá.. O meu sistema operacional é Windows.. E lá fala sobre Linux.. E eu já troquei os dois armazenamentos no Android manifest.. Se colocar interno da certo, porém se tentar abrir o app sem ser direto pelo eclipse não funciona.. Fala que não foi instalado

Comment: @VictorAugusto vc sabia q o android roda no linux kernel?

Comment: você pode tentar  android:installLocation="auto"